# Javascript: Best way to delete item which contains objects with listener from array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

What is best way to remove item that contains objects with listener from array? I'm mostly worried about object listeners.

Here is how I create my array:

```
array_list.push({data: data, marker: marker, label: label});
```

data contains information, marker is google map marker and label is div -element that is visible for user. Marker and label has listeners added.

I have figured out a couple ways to clear my item from array (easy way):

```
function remove_item(i) {
  var label = array_list[i]['label'];
  array_list = array_list.filter(function (obj) {
    return obj.label !== label;
  });
}
```

Another way is this:

```
function remove_item(i) {
  var label = array_list[i]['label'];
  array_list = array_list.filter(function (obj) {
    if (obj.label == label) {
      obj.data = null;
      obj.marker = null;
      obj.label = null;
      return null;
    }
    else {
      return obj;
    }
  });
}
```

Splice -method (also easy):

```
function remove_item(i) {
  array_list.splice(i, 1);
}
```

Which is the best way to delete item with included listeners or is there better way? Let me know, please. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I dont know about best way but why go beyond using `function remove_item(i) {
  array_list.splice(i, 1);
}`.  3 lines of code that does what you want it to do. Why complicate things?

Comment: Thanks for answer. You are right. Why complicate things? I go with splice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a solution where an object is cleared and the item is spliced from an array.

```
function remove_item(i) {
  var item = array_list[i];

  // Remove marker from map
  item['marker'].setMap(null);

  // Remove label from html list content
  item['label'].parentElement.removeChild(item['label']);

  // Set Objects to null
  item['data'] = null;
  item['marker'] = null;
  item['label'] = null;
  array_list.splice(i, 1);
}
```

I hope that this helps someone else also. Comments and suggestions are welcome.